# Karma-webpack: Unknown provider: LeaveServiceProvider <- LeaveService

Tags: angularjs, testing, webpack, karma-runner, karma-webpack

My app works like a charm but I can't run my tests with

```
$ yarn test
# node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start ./karma.conf.js --single-run
```

#### Version

```
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.10",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
```

#### Error

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) leave API service create(): should create a leave FAILED
        Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: LeaveServiceProvider <- LeaveService
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.10/$injector/unpr?p0=LeaveServiceProvider%20%3C-%20LeaveService (line 4674)
        static/app.min.js:4674:87
        getService@static/app.min.js:4827:40
        static/app.min.js:4679:49
        getService@static/app.min.js:4827:40
        injectionArgs@static/app.min.js:4852:69
        invoke@static/app.min.js:4874:32
        WorkFn@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3130:26
        inject@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3100:46
        test/leave.service.tests.js:55:23
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
        inject@node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3097:28
        test/leave.service.tests.js:55:23
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
        TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectPOST') in test/leave.service.tests.js (line 64)
        test/leave.service.tests.js:64:16
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
        TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation') in test/leave.service.tests.js (line 114)
        test/leave.service.tests.js:114:16
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 5 (1 FAILED) (skipped 4) ERROR (0.042 secs / 0.01 secs)
```

#### Karma.conf.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'mocha', 'chai'],
        files: [
            './static/app.min.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            {pattern: 'test/leave.service.tests.js'}
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'test/leave.service.tests.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            module: webpackConfig.module,
            plugins: webpackConfig.plugins
        },
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },
        notifyReporter: {
            reportEachFailure: true,
            reportSuccess: false
        },
        plugins: [
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-chai'
        ],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
    });
};
```

#### webpack.conf.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src2/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
        publicPath: '/static/',
        filename: 'app.min.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            moment: 'moment'
        })
    ],

    resolve: {
        root: path.resolve('./src2'),
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'},
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'},
            {test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            {test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        proxy: {
            '/api': {
                target: {
                    host: '0.0.0.0',
                    protocol: 'http:',
                    port: 8000
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

#### test/leave.service.js

```
var chai = require('chai');
var assert = chai.assert;

describe('leave API service', function () {
    var service;
    var $httpBackend;


    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, LeaveService) {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        service = LeaveService;
    }));

    it('create(): should create a leave', function (done) {
        var foo = 'bar';

        assert.equal(foo, 'bar');
        done();
    });
});
```

#### Question

What's the matter here ?

related: [Karma-webpack+angular TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectPOST'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41618626/802365)

Comment: I had this problem when improperly injecting angular services in my controller unit tests. Are you sure the $httpBackend is properly injected in your LeaveService? Seeing the error, your problem comes from your test, not your config.

Comment: I agree but the test was working with before using. Could you elaborate on the injection issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to a really simple test and add complexity step by step until it fails. The solution was to:

1. inject my app `angular.mock.module('app')`

   ```
   beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));
   ```
2. inject the dependencies with `angular.mock.inject()`

   ```
   beforeEach(function () {
       angular.mock.inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _LeaveService_) {
           $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
           service = _LeaveService_;
       });
   });
   ```
3. load the built `app`, `angular-mock` and the `test/**/*.js` in `karma.conf.js`:

   ```
   files: [
       './static/app.min.js',
       'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
       {pattern: 'test/foo.service.tests.js'}
   ]
   ```

### Full code below

#### foo.service.tests.js

```
var chai = require('chai');
var assert = chai.assert;

describe('leave API service', function () {
    var service;
    var $httpBackend;


    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _LeaveService_) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            service = _LeaveService_;
        });
    });

    it('create(): should create a leave', function (done) {
        var foo = 'bar';


        assert.equal(foo, 'bar');
        done();
    });
});
```

#### webpack.conf.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin');

module.exports = {
        entry: {
                app: './src/app.js'
        },
        output: {
                path: path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
                publicPath: '/static/',
                filename: '[name]-[hash:8].min.js'
        },
        plugins: [
                new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
                new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                        $: 'jquery',
                        jQuery: 'jquery',
                        moment: 'moment',
                        Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util'
                }),
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                        template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src', 'index.html'),
                        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
                        alwaysWriteToDisk: true
                }),
                new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin()
        ],
        resolve: {alias: {Services: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/services/')}},
        module: {
                rules: [
                        {test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
                        {test: /\.scss$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']},
                        {test: /\.html$/, use: ['html-loader']},
                        {test: /src.*\.js$/, use: ['ng-annotate-loader']},
                        {test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
                        {test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader'}
                ]
        },
        devServer: {
                port: 8080,
                proxy: {
                        '/api': {target: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000'},
                        '/exports': {target: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000'},
                        '/media': {target: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000'}
                }
        }
};
```

#### Karma.con.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'mocha', 'chai'],
        files: [
            './static/app.min.js',
            'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            {pattern: 'test/foo.service.tests.js'}
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            'test/foo.service.tests.js': ['webpack']
        },
        webpack: {
            module: webpackConfig.module,
            plugins: webpackConfig.plugins
        },
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: 'errors-only'
        },
        notifyReporter: {
            reportEachFailure: true,
            reportSuccess: false
        },
        plugins: [
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-chai'
        ],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS']
    });
};
```

Comment: your `webpack.conf.js` snippet is the same as `karma.conf.js`

Answer (score 0):

When an Angular controller or a service depends on another Angular object (service, factory, constant...), the injector will look for it in the providers list (an array of singleton constructors). If there is no injector, or the dependency does not exist, angular will exit with an error like the one you have (no provider xProvider for service x). This should be resolved by mocking the angular module and attach depending services to it (method 1), or instantiate your LeaveService with a function returning an object filled with methods as its dependency argument, like

```
// leave-service.spec.js
...
var FakeHttpService = function() {
  return {
    get: function(url) { return new Promise(); },
    post: function(url, data) { return new Promise(); },
    //...
  };
};
var leaveService = new LeaveService(new FakeHttpService());
```

Next, when you do something like `var res = leaveService.get(url)`, it should call the FakeHttpService get method.

You should read the [Angular Documentation on $httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) for further details about testing services that use the $http service (method 1), and understand how the injector works in a test environment.

Comment: Thanks for the recall about injection but mocking the service I want to test is not a good idea.